# Are the rationals definable in any number field?

Tags: lo.logic, algebraic-number-theory, model-theory, number-fields

Let $K$ be a number field. Is it necessarily true that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a first-order definable subset of $K$? Equivalently (since in any number field, its ring of integers is a definable subset), is $\mathbb{Z}$ necessarily a definable subset of $K$, or of $\cal{O}_K$?

Edit: And if not, is $\mathbb{Q}$ always interpretable in $K$?

Comment: Variation on a theme: there's no uniform way to define $\Bbb F_p$ in $\Bbb F_{p^2}$, Chatzidakis, van den Dries, Macintyre, Definable sets over  finite fields, J. Reine Angew. Math. 427

Comment: While this is a different question, $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Z$ are not definable in $\tilde{\mathbb Q}$ and $\tilde{\mathbb Z}$. In fact, the ring $\tilde{\mathbb Z}$ is decidable (see Van den Dries, *Elimination theory for the ring of algebraic integers*, and Prestel and Schmid, *Existentially closed domains with radical relations*).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to R. S. Rumely, Undecidability and Definability for the theory of global fields, AMS Trans., 262, pp. 195-217, prime subfield is always definable in global field, and in number case, you can define $\Bbb N$.